# Cannot override serializer config in SonataUserBundle to hide properties

Tags: symfony, serialization, sonata-user-bundle, jms-serializer

I am using **SonataUserBundle** and **JMSSerializerBundle** and I would like to hide the token and other properties of my serialized object.

The file I want to ovvride in **SonataUserBundle** is **Resources/config/serializer/Model.User.xml** .

Here is my configuration:

**app/config.yml**

`jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            - { path: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/SoantaUserBundle/serializer, namespace_prefix: 'Sonata\UserBundle' }
            - { path: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/FOSUserBundle/serializer, namespace_prefix: 'FOS\UserBundle' }`

and in **app/Resources/SonataUserBundle/serializer** I have tried 2 files.

**Model.User.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serializer>
    <class name="Sonata\UserBundle\Model\User" exclusion-policy="all" xml-root-name="user">
        <property name="token" type="string"  expose="false" since-version="1.0" groups="sonata_api_read,sonata_api_write,sonata_search" />
    </class>
</serializer>`

**Model.User.yml**

`Sonata\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        token:
            expose: false`

Both files dont seem to work.

I have managed to hide some properties from the **FOSUserBundle**, but seems I have troubles hiding the ones related to **SonataUserBundle**. I'm not sure if it's relevant but I would like to mention that I am using also am using **HWIOauthBundle**.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't think you need autodetection since you're specifying also the directories. Then you have a couple of typos in the sonata directory path:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            - { path: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/SonataUserBundle/serializer, namespace_prefix: 'Sonata\UserBundle' }
```